# Career Full of Excitement

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> You may think I'm a drone,
> Some say I'm a rumour,
> But near to a murder,
> I've no sense of humour.
>
> When I'm at a road,
> You'll notice a bird,
> Some fashionable jargon
> From me and a word.
>
> At the head of marines,
> You may see me trim,
> With a unit of distance,
> From an actor, named Tim.
>
> I count in fives,
> As part of a game,
> But two is my number,
> A household name.

**Who/what am I?**
**In your answer, please explain each line of the riddle.**

Comment: Lines 3-4 and 15-16 gave me a possible answer, but I can't make it fit very well with the rest ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are a

> BUZZ

You may think I'm a drone,

> If you hear a buzz, you may think of say a male bee

Some say I'm a rumour,

> Buzz is gossip or rumour.

But near to a murder, I've no sense of humour.

> A buzz kill stops the fun.

When I'm at a road, You'll notice a bird,

> The buzzard, buzz at a Rd.

Some fashionable jargon, From me and a word.

> A buzzword is jargon, popular in some circles.

At the head of marines,You may see me trim,

> Marines have buzzcuts which are close-cropped hair styles.

With a unit of distance, From an actor, named Tim.

> Tim Allen voiced Buzz Lightyear in Toy Story.

I count in fives,As part of a game,

> Fizz Buzz can be write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100 and for multiples of 3 print Fizz instead, and for the multiples of 5 print Buzz.

But two is my number, A household name.

> Buzz Aldrin, the second man on the moon.

Title: Career Full of Excitement

> Buzz is excitement

Comment: Drone probably means people droning on something, like a teacher droning on in class. It can also be defined as a 'buzz'

Comment: Great work Tom! For the first line I was thinking along the lines of what UnidentifiedX said but your explanation works just as well. Also for the first line in the last paragraph this is also a children's game as well as being a programming task (with the same idea).